# Incorrect handling of Play templates by IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

With IDEA 13.1.5 and the Play 2.0 Support plugin version 0.41.2 (which I believe are the latest versions), Play templates seem to have some partial recognition in IDEA.

The syntax highlighting is correct and a very limited amount of auto suggest works (for example, `@test = {}` will allow working auto suggest with `@test.`.

However, IDEA seems to think that most of the file is incorrect. It doesn't recognize arguments (eg, the `@(whatever: Html)` at the top of the file complains that it can't resolve symbol `whatever` (even though it's a declaration). Templates that have curried arguments cause IDEA to complain about "wrong top statement declaration". None of these arguments are recognized throughout the template (and thus there's no auto suggest and the file gets covered in "errors", which prevents you from finding real errors).

Despite that, most functions seem to be found fine (eg, a call to `@Messages("foo")` is not flagged as an error).

My templates are saved with the extension `.scala.html`. Everything compiles correctly (ie, there's no real errors). The inability to find real errors while typing and lack of auto suggest hurt my productivity (especially with how slow it is to compile the pages).

Is there anything I can do make IDEA "work" with Play templates (ie, not incorrectly flag things as errors, auto suggest on variables, etc)?

If not, is there at least anything I can do to stifle this incorrect error handling?

Comment: These days (I'm using IntelliJ 14 with the Scala plugin version 1.4.15) it looks like support for Play view templates has been removed entirely. They don't even get syntax highlighting, let alone error checking. Hopefully this comes back in the future (in a less broken way).

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of Idea are you using? Idea supports twirl highligthing only with the paid "Ultimate edition"